# Still getting "Task exception was never retrieved" even after calling .exception() on pending tasks

Tags: python, python-asyncio

So I have a code that generally looks like this:

```py
async def do_job(a: int):
    # actions that may raise an exception
    ...

async def fun(jobs: list[int]):
    max_exc = 5
    pending_tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(do_job(a)) for a in jobs
    ]
    count_exc = 0
    while pending_tasks:
        done, pending_tasks = await asyncio.wait(pending_tasks, timeout=30)
        for task in done:
            if exc := task.exception():
                print(f"\n{task.get_name()} raised Exception: <{type(exc)}> {exc}")
                count_exc += 1
                continue
            # Do things with successful task
            ...
        if count_exc > max_exc:
            break
    if count_exc > max_exc:
        print("Too many exceptions happened, cancelling pending tasks")
        for task in pending_tasks:
            task.cancel()
        while pending_tasks:
            done, pending_tasks = await asyncio.wait(pending_tasks, return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED)
            for task in done:
                if not isinstance((exc := task.exception()), asyncio.CancelledError):
                    print(f"\n{task.get_name()} raised Exception: <{type(exc)}> {exc}")
        raise RuntimeError("Too many exceptions")
```

I still get the `Task exception was never retrieved` error.

I did grab the task exceptions with `.exception()`, so receiving that error is unexpected.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce any error with your code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I don't see anything in your code actually cancelling the pending tasks. And if there was, `task.exception()` should raise the `CancelledError` before you can do `isinstance`.

Comment: @AlexHall whoops I accidentally deleted those lines. I'll restore them

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3.11 or newer, the canonical way to manage a group of tasks and cancel them all together if one of them fails is to use a [`TaskGroup`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-groups). Since you want to allow some exceptions, you can catch the exception before it ends the task when the count is low enough:

```py
import asyncio


async def fun(jobs: list[int]):
    max_exc = 5
    exc_count = 0

    async def do_job(x: int):
        await asyncio.sleep(x / 3)
        print("Done sleeping")
        try:
            x / 0
        except Exception:
            nonlocal exc_count
            exc_count += 1
            if exc_count > max_exc:
                print("Too many exceptions happened, cancelling pending tasks")
                raise
            else:
                print(f"Exception {exc_count} of {max_exc} happened, continuing")

    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as g:
        for a in jobs:
            g.create_task(do_job(a))


async def main():
    await fun([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])


asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
Done sleeping
Exception 1 of 5 happened, continuing
Done sleeping
Exception 2 of 5 happened, continuing
Done sleeping
Exception 3 of 5 happened, continuing
Done sleeping
Exception 4 of 5 happened, continuing
Done sleeping
Exception 5 of 5 happened, continuing
Done sleeping
Too many exceptions happened, cancelling pending tasks
  + Exception Group Traceback (most recent call last):
  |   File "/home/alex/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.3/scratches/scratch_1607.py", line 31, in <module>
  |     asyncio.run(main())
  |   File "/home/alex/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 194, in run
  |     return runner.run(main)
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |   File "/home/alex/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
  |     return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |   File "/home/alex/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 684, in run_until_complete
  |     return future.result()
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |   File "/home/alex/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.3/scratches/scratch_1607.py", line 28, in main
  |     await fun([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
  |   File "/home/alex/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.3/scratches/scratch_1607.py", line 22, in fun
  |     async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as g:
  |   File "/home/alex/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/asyncio/taskgroups.py", line 145, in __aexit__
  |     raise me from None
  | ExceptionGroup: unhandled errors in a TaskGroup (1 sub-exception)
  +-+---------------- 1 ----------------
    | Traceback (most recent call last):
    |   File "/home/alex/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.3/scratches/scratch_1607.py", line 12, in do_job
    |     x / 0
    |     ~~^~~
    | ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
    +------------------------------------
```